# Script Extension for OOo or Word?

Tags: scripting, ms-word, syntax-highlighting, openoffice.org, libreoffice

I'am a student in informatique and actually in internship I'd like to keep note of what I'm doing.
So for this I'm using OpenOffice.org (I can aswell use Word its not a pb).

But in the process I'm facing a sad problem I can't find (maybe because there is not) an extension for copying code in my report.

I'm using Shell, Js, HTML, PHP, CSS and all classical Web developpement environnement langage.

Does some of you has allready heard of something for it ?

Where can I find it pls :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some extensions for Apache OpenOffice or LibreOffice:

- Openoffice: [Code Colorizer](http://extensions.openoffice.org/de/project/code-colorizer)
- LibreOffice: [Coooder](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/coooder)
- LibreOffice: [Code Colorizer Formatter](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/code-colorizer-formatter)

Comment: Ty :) Work perfectly with LibreOffice !